# Bounding Box not updated

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I use the function GetCollisionBoundingBox() on a box model to get the minimun corner of this box (green point). From this point I compute two new points to grab the box with a robotic arm. This method works well as long as the box doesn't move. Then, if the box is moved, the min corner of the bounding is not correct anymore. You can see on the picture below what is happening.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/41n4svs6m40mkfn/default_gzclient_camera%281%29-2016-02-13T21_16_07.726404.jpg?dl=0

Dou you have an idea why this happens ? Does anyone know how the bounding box of an object is updated (I use ODE) ?

Thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12596/bounding-box-not-updated/) by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 198 on 2016-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, this might be related to [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1325/getboundingbox-returns-the-models-last) older issue. Give it some votes, it might get fixed faster.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) on 2016-02-17**:
Well seen, thx.